connecting android emulator to local adress
I want to connect my android emulator to a node js local server running localhost:2000, I searched and found a way to do it but it does not work.
The local host name in the settings of the emulator takes localhost so I used localhost as the host name, i tried using the ip address of the laptop but it invalid proxy
import 'dart:convert';

    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    
    class Http {
      static String url = "http://10.0.2.2:2000/api/";
      static postProduct(Map pData) async {
        try {
          final response = await http.post(
            Uri.parse("${url}add_product"),
            body: pData,
          );[![enter image description here][1]][1]
          if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
            print(data);
          } else {
            print('Failed to load data');
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print(e.toString());
        }
      }
    }


host name]1


Instead of connecting to localhost, connect to your computer’s IP address. You can find one if you go to command line and type ipconfig/all (on windows). So swap localhost to your IP in dart code and you should be fine with no further configuration

I did not use local host in the code. I used my android emulator ip adrdress '      static String url = "http://10.0.2.2:2000/api/";
'
